# How can I programmatically connect and disconnect vpn connections by using android's "openvpn connect" app in combination with intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, openvpn

I'm working on an android app that should start an OpenVPN Connect session automatically when needed.

How can I programmatically connect and disconnect vpn connections by using android's "openvpn connect" app in combination with intents ?

Edit:
Meanwhile I found this approach - it works for me:

```
private void startVPN() {
    Intent openVPN = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    openVPN.setPackage("net.openvpn.openvpn");
    openVPN.setClassName("net.openvpn.openvpn", net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVPNClient");
    openVPN.putExtra("net.openvpn.openvpn.AUTOSTART_PROFILE_NAME", "10.10.10.10 [profilename]");
    startActivityForResult(openVPN, 0);
}
```

This starts the "OpenVPN Connect" app and uses the profilename to do an auto-connect.

If successfull the app goes to background by itself.

Is there even a way to do this completly in background ?
Stopping the VPN-connection does everything in background.

```
private void stopVPN() {
    Intent openVPN = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    openVPN.setPackage("net.openvpn.openvpn");
    openVPN.setClassName("net.openvpn.openvpn", "net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVPNDisconnect");
    startActivityForResult(openVPN, 0);
}
```

Comment: i'm interested in this, wonder where you found this so i could dig more, for example, passing a "*.ovpn" file as profile ...

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN's official Android client can be invoked through AIDL. There's an entire sample app available, with [source code](https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/browse/#hg%2FremoteExample). It even has a relatively friendly license.

Comment: thanks for this info; would like to stick to "OpenVPN Connect" as long as possible. Since there is an iOS version as well and a future app porting should be a little smoother :)

Comment: "future app porting should be a little smoother" -- I wouldn't expect that at all. They're very different platforms.